# Why does a Rails engine's gem name have to "match" the module/namespace name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, module, namespaces, rubygems

I am building my first Rails engine.  I called it `my_engine`, so it generates the files

```
lib/my_engine.rb
lib/my_engine/engine.rb
lib/my_engine/version.rb
```

That all have the module named `MyEngine`.  And in the gemspec, the gem name is also set to `my_engine`.

If I create a model `my_model`, it goes into `app/models/my_engine/my_model.rb`, and is generated as

```
module MyEngine
  class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

If I make a class method in here, and put the gem in a Rails project, it all works fine.

```
def self.hello
  "Hello from your Engine's model!"
end

$ bundle exec rails c
[1] (pry) main: 0> MyEngine::MyModel.hello
=> "Hello from your Engine's model!"
```

---

However, I do not want the gem name to be `my_engine`.  But if I change the name in the gemspec to something else, like `what-i-really-want-to-name-it`, everything stops working.  Rails cannot see my model, although it can see my namespace.  I am indeed changing the gem name in the Rails app and re-bundling, so it's not an issue of that.

```
$ bundle exec rails c
[1] (pry) main: 0> MyEngine::VERSION
=> "0.0.1"   # default version from engine generation
[2] (pry) main: 0> MyEngine::MyModel.hello
NameError: uninitialized constant MyEngine::MyModel
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'
```

---

Why is "this" tied directly to the gem name?  Is there any kind of workaround for this?  I would really like to have the gem name and the module name to be different values.

**Using:  Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0**

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that one of Rails' foundational concepts is:

> [Convention over configuration.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Convention_Over_Configuration)

When you decide to override the principle of Convention with Configuration, that's a Rails anti-pattern. Is it possible to to do it and be happy and have a working Rails app? Sure, but it's not code you would want to show as an example of your work on a Rails app.

So, the convention is that the module name matches the gem name. It's just a convention, but since convention is the mutually agreed law in Rails town, you're going anti-pattern when you don't follow it.

**Added in response to OP comment**

Rails engines are typified by the fact they use an isolated namespace and isolated resources. Gems don't, so in effect, the answer is yes, using a Rails engine does enforce a namespace convention that does not exist for a gem.  And that namespacing is used by the middleware to keep the main_app separated from the engine at runtime. Two examples to illustrate:

An extreme example: you can have an app mounted as as engine on itself. Namespacing isolates one from the other so the middleware services act on the right processes which are *only* differentiated by the namespace.

Another example: 2 engines mounted on a main_app. Now there are essentially 3 apps running. How would you want to implement non-conventional namespace isolation in this case?

**So...**
It is possible to hammer in a nonconforming namespace in a Rails engine? Probably. I've never tried. **But your engine will not be portable. And worse, someone installing it will not be able to mount another engine that is conforming (and sharing the main_app and the middleware stack) because you've forced them into a configuration maze that breaks a conventional Rails engine.** This last part is a theory.

Comment: Yeah, I get Rails conventions and patterns.  I just thought that this was more of a gem issue.  Could I not make a "regular" gem that does what I want with no problem?  Or does introducing the Rails::Engine automatically "enforce" the pattern?  What if I want multiple namespaces within the engine?  Is that an anti-pattern too?

Comment: Last comment struck. I've worked with engines, but not gems, so let me clarify in the answer.